# Error en python3 manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

He creado varios modelos en mi archivo models.py. Con el fin de guardar estos cambios, he intentado ejecutar el comando python3 manage.py makemigrations y luego python3 manage.py migrate. Sin embargo, al ejecutar estos comandos, me encuentro con un error que indica que no se encuentran las librerías de la base de datos (o eso creo), a pesar de que ya las he instalado en múltiples ocasiones.

A continuación, te proporciono el mensaje de error completo que estoy recibiendo:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
 line 25, in <module>
     import psycopg as Database   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/__init__.py",
 line 9, in <module>
     from . import pq  # noqa: F401 import early to stabilize side effects   File
 "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/pq/__init__.py",
 line 114, in <module>
     import_from_libpq()   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg/pq/__init__.py",
 line 106, in import_from_libpq
     raise ImportError( ImportError: no pq wrapper available. Attempts made:
 - couldn't import psycopg 'c' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_c'
 - couldn't import psycopg 'binary' implementation: No module named 'psycopg_binary'
 - couldn't import psycopg 'python' implementation: libpq library not found
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
 line 27, in <module>
     import psycopg2 as Database ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "/mnt/c/Users/casaadmin/OneDrive -
 Casa/Escritorio/proyecto/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
     main()   File "/mnt/c/Users/casaadmin/OneDrive - Casa/Escritorio/proyecto/manage.py", line 18, in main
     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
 line 442, in execute_from_command_line 
     utility.execute()   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py",
 line 416, in execute
     django.setup()   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/__init__.py",
 line 24, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
 line 116, in populate
     app_config.import_models()   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
 line 269, in import_models
     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in
 import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File
 "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File
 "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked  
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in
 exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in
 _call_with_frames_removed   File "/mnt/c/Users/casaadmin/OneDrive - Casa/Escritorio/proyecto/beleroforms_app/models.py", line 22, in
 <module>
     class Responsable(models.Model):   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
 line 143, in __new__
     new_class.add_to_class("_meta", Options(meta, app_label))   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
 line 371, in add_to_class
     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py",
 line 243, in contribute_to_class
     self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length()   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py",
 line 15, in __getattr__
     return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py",
 line 62, in __getitem__
     conn = self.create_connection(alias)   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
 line 193, in create_connection
     backend = load_backend(db["ENGINE"])   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
 line 113, in load_backend
     return import_module("%s.base" % backend_name)   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in
 import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import   File
 "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load   File
 "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked  
 File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in
 exec_module   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in
 _call_with_frames_removed   File "/home/casaadmin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
 line 29, in <module>
     raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 or psycopg module") django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading
 psycopg2 or psycopg module
```

Comment: Verificaste que efectivamente tengas instalado Psycopg2? Deberías ejecutar en una consola "pip freeze" para comprobar. Por lo que indica el error el modulo no esta siendo encontrado. Por otra parte, estableciste en tu settings.py correctamente los parámetros de la conexión?

Comment: Este es mi requirements.txt: 
asgiref==3.6.0
Django==4.2.1
greenlet==2.0.2
numpy==1.24.3
pandas==2.0.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.6
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==2.0.15
sqlparse==0.4.4
typing_extensions==4.6.0
tzdata==2023.3
azure-identity==1.10.0
azure-keyvault==4.2.0
python-dotenv==1.0.0
uvicorn==0.22.0

Comment: y esto es lo que me dice el comando que me has dicho: 
dbus-python==1.2.18
distro==1.7.0
distro-info==1.1+ubuntu0.1
Django==4.2.4
httplib2==0.20.2
importlib-metadata==4.6.4
jeepney==0.7.1
keyring==23.5.0
launchpadlib==1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.4
lazr.uri==1.0.6
more-itertools==8.10.0
netifaces==0.11.0
oauthlib==3.2.0
psycopg==3.1.10
PyGObject==3.42.1
PyJWT==2.3.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-apt==2.4.0+ubuntu2
PyYAML==5.4.1
SecretStorage==3.3.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
systemd-python==234
typing_extensions==4.7.1
ubuntu-advantage-tools==8001

Comment: Pues ahí tienes el problema, tienes instalado psycopg==3.1.10 en lugar de psycopg2, estas realizando un import psycopg2 y no tienes instalado el modulo. Debes ejecutar un pip install psycopg2-binary==2.9.6

Comment: pero, ahora que he hecho el makemigrations, tengo que hacer el migrate. Y me sale error... Como te lo puedo proporcionar?

Comment: Pero ya ese es otro poblema. Si ya pudiste ejecutar el makemigrations sin problemas es un avance. Que error te muestra al intentar migrar? Te recuerdo que la base de datos a la cual intentes migrar ya debe existir en tu gestor de base de datos.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147950/discussion-between-julian-buxton-and-ernesto-rincon).